# Inheritance or delegation for Repositories

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, delegates

Say I have a Repository (a kind of object for accessing data) interface.
I made up a simple one just for this question.

```
interface UserRepository {
   void insert(final User user);
   void update(final User user);
   List<User> findAll();
}
```

Now, because I manage different kinds of DBMS, this repository is implemented by:

```
class MySqlUserRepository implements UserRepository { ... }
class OracleUserRepository implements UserRepository { ... }
class SqlServerUserRepository implements UserRepository { ... }
```

Being that most of the SQL statements can be shared among those implementations, the first thing I'd do is add an Abstract base class, which provides all the basic implementations.

```
abstract class AbstractUserRepository implements UserRepository {
   // Provide access to statements
   private final Configuration configuration;

   // Provides access to JDBC operations
   private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   AbstractUserRepository(
         final Configuration configuration,
         final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
      this.configuration = configuration;
      this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
   }

   ... Implementations
}
```

So all the implementations now `extends AbstractUserRepository`.
However, I have to override a method on `OracleUserRepository` to use a different statement...

```
class OracleUserRepository extends AbstractUserRepository {
   private final Configuration configuration;
   private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   OracleUserRepository(
         final Configuration configuration,
         final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
      super(configuration, jdbcTemplate);
      this.configuration = configuration.subset("user.sql.oracle");
      this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
   }

   @Override
   public void update(final User user) {
      // Use Configuration and JdbcTemplate
   }

   ...
}
```

... and a couple of methods on `SqlServerUserRepository`, using the same approach, obviously.

---

Now, you can see we are already duplicating class properties, and maybe the methods are basically the same:

`AbstractUserRepository#update`:

```
void update(final User user) {
   final var parameters =
                new MapSqlParameterSource()
                        .addValue("field1", user.field1)
                        .addValue("field2", user.field2);

   jdbcTemplate.update(configuration.getString("user.sql.update"), parameters);
}
```

`OracleUserRepository#update`:

```
void update(final User user) {
   final var parameters =
                new MapSqlParameterSource()
                        .addValue("field1", user.field1)
                        .addValue("field2", user.field2);

   // Note the subtle difference. We got a "subset" (user.sql.oracle) in the constructor
   jdbcTemplate.update(configuration.getString("update"), parameters);
}
```

This doesn't feel right to me, too much duplication already. Don't you think too?

---

A different approach would be using delegation. This mean having a detached object, which does not inherit the `UserRepository` interface, and which has methods that accept also SQL statements instead of only an object.

```
class UserRepositoryDelegate {
   private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate,

   UserRepositoryDelegate(final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
      this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
   } 

   public void update(
          final String statement,
          final User user) {
       final var parameters =
                    new MapSqlParameterSource()
                            .addValue("field1", user.field1)
                            .addValue("field2", user.field2);

       jdbcTemplate.update(statement, parameters);
   }

   ...
}
```

This object would be injected in the other Repositories:

```
class OracleUserRepository implements UserRepository {
   private final Configuration configuration;
   private final UserRepositoryDelegate delegate;

   OracleUserRepository(
         final Configuration configuration,
         final UserRepositoryDelegate delegate) {
      this.configuration = configuration.subset("user.sql.oracle");
      this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   @Override
   public void update(final User user) {
      delegate.update(configuration.get("update"), user);
   }

   ...
}
```

And the `AbstractUserRepository` could become a concrete `GenericUserRepository` (notice I don't get a subset of the properties for a specific DBMS, but instead use the generic ones):

```
class GenericUserRepository implements UserRepository {
   private final Configuration configuration;
   private final UserRepositoryDelegate delegate;

   GenericUserRepository(
         final Configuration configuration,
         final UserRepositoryDelegate delegate) {
      this.configuration = configuration;
      this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   @Override
   public void update(final User user) {
      delegate.update(configuration.get("user.sql.update"), user);
   }

   ...
}
```

The `GenericUserRepository` can also be used by other implementations:

```
class MySqlUserRepository implements UserRepository {
   private final GenericUserRepository genericUserRepository;

   MySqlUserRepository(final GenericUserRepository genericUserRepository) {
      this.genericUserRepository = genericUserRepository;
   }

   @Override
   public void update(final User user) {
      genericUserRepository.update(user);
   }

   ...
}
```

Is the delegate approach a better strategy for this specific case?
Would you have solved this "problem" in a different way?

Edit: to let you understand more, the only one and correct Repository implementation is choosen at start-up time, and injected in a single, concrete, `UserService`.

Comment: Uhm, ok writing this code is in itself an useful exercise. But if you plan to use it for real projects, consider the available alternatives- like hibernate, jpa or spring data (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories)

Comment: @Daniele I was just writing another edit, explaining that the use of an ORM (such as Hibernate or EclipseLink) or libraries similar  to MyBatis is out-of-scope for this question.
I already use JPA for other projects. This is purely a design question

Comment: I would also like to specify that pre-requisites such as hot-reloading of statements, sometimes mandates the use of pure JDBC (maybe using the Spring JDBC abstraction, as is for this question)